# MDNS protocol is normal?

Tags: lan

I have a LAN with about 120 PCs, in the last 2 weeks I am facing a problem, the network sometimes go very slow and sometimes the users cannot reach the internet ( the router will be unreachable) and I have to restart the router and the switches, So I am starting using wireshark, Is this traffic in the picture normal? If No, what is thealt text solution?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

mDNS is used (amongst others) by Apple's [Bonjour service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)), so if 192.168.0.28, .89 and .240 are Apple devices this is normal, if they are Windows devices running Apple software (e.g. iTunes) this is also normal.

[The wikipedia article about mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) also mentions other zeroconf implementations use mDNS, such as [Avahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)) in Linux.

I hope this answers your question "is mDNS normal?"; if you would like help troubleshooting the actual problem I suggest you post a separate question for that, with more details about the network (make and model of the network devices, their configuration, a topology drawing) and more details about the problem.

Comment: It's not just iTunes. It's many services on OSX and (Apple) IOS as well, and also not just Apple: Avahi on Linux uses mDNS too for device discovery.

Comment: @TeunVink: I didn't say it's only iTunes?

Comment: No, but the way I read it you made it sound as if having iTunes is the trigger for bonjour to be working, my point was that it's not (at least on Apple OS'es).

Comment: @TeunVink: fair point, I've rephrased the answer.